# C++ How to find pair of 3 integers in vector< pair<int, pair<int, int> > >

Tags: c++, vector, find

For example, I store 3 elements simultaneously like:

`vector< pair<int, pair<int, int> > > myvec;`
 `myvec.push_back(make_pair(1, make_pair(2, 3)));`
How can I check if {1,2,3} exist (as a pair) in myvec?

Comment: Can you use instead `std::tuple<int, int, int>`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean _"exist (as a pair) "_? {1, 2, 3} isn't a _pair_ but a tuple of three values, right? Mind to [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63759863/edit) what exactly you want to achieve please?

Comment: Jessie is possibly new to C++, guys. Jessie is unaware of the notation. So used {} instead of <>. Let us be kind. We can see that Jessie is talking about of `pair<int, pair<int, int>>`. And why did you both assume {1,2,3} is a tuple? it could be a vector as well. Jessie is a new contributor. It's fine. Please remove the downvotes on the two answers below.

Comment: @Shridhar Well that's why we ask Jessie in our comments. As is the question is unclear atm, and shouldn't be answer until it's made clearer. To do that is Jessies job. Only they can know.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [find()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) from `algorithm`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    vector< pair<int, pair<int, int> > > myvec;  
    auto p = make_pair(1, make_pair(2, 3));
    myvec.push_back(p);
    
    if ( std::find(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), p) != myvec.end() )
        cout << "Found";
    else
        cout << "Not Found";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Editing the question to better meet a match for your answer is inappropriate, if not abusive.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Hey, I can give an answer for searching a tuple in vector too. It is not about editing question to match our answers. We need to understand the contributor is new and possibly new to C++ as well. We need to be compassionate enough to understand what OP is talking about. We can very well see that `pair<int, pair<int,int>>` is being used and needs to be searched.

Answer (score -1):

sure, you can do this:

```
 for (auto mval: myvec) {
   if (mval.first == 1 && mval.second.first == 2 && mval.second.second == 3)
     cout << "Found" << endl;
 }
```

or this:

```
typedef pair<int,int> IntPair;
typedef pair<int, IntPair> MyPair;
 
...
for (auto mval: myvec) {
   if (mval == MyPair(1, IntPair(2, 3)))
     cout << "Found" << endl;
 }
```

or a few other ways.